# Protecting Quality posts

Tags: discussion, moderation

Users of SO would be familiar with this. In order to protect good quality posts and answers, we have the moderators "protect" a question. A good example would be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33155331/are-and-operators-sufficient-to-make-every-possible-logical-expression) question.

I have come across many such great quality posts on SQA- like [this](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2197/how-to-download-a-file-using-seleniums-webdriver) and many others.

I see that many times, new users, add questions/doubts in form of comments -since they don't have the reputation to comment. And then they have to be informed about adding a new question or any other remedy.

Do we have this "protection" option available to SQA moderators also? If so, why don't we use it?

Comment: Yes, this is available and I have seen posts like this http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/211/whats-the-difference-between-testing-and-quality-assurance with the protected mode on. Ofcourse there are very fewer posts available with this mode on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, yes we absolutely can, as diamond mods, protect posts. So can any user with [3500 rep or higher](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions).

Second, I find a lot of sites have two major problems with protecting their posts. First, it's used way too much. I would only protect a post that 1) has an external source of a lot of attention, like being featured in a blog post or tweeted by a twitter with a lot of followers and 2) is actively being abused by new users.

I would agree that the posts on that could use some cleanup, and you could argue that I could be more aggressive in removing some of the lower quality posts instead of waiting for people to come back and clean them up themselves. (You'll note for some of the lower quality ones I've left comments asking them to make changes.) But I wouldn't say this is a prime candidate for being protected - if a post gets a bad answer once a month, it doesn't need to be protected.

I base my thought process around [Shog's post on the matter](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/changes-and-guidelines-for-the-protected-question-status/). If you feel a question should be protected, flag it and we'll take a look. If you feel an answer should be deleted but has somehow slipped through the review process, flag and and we'll take a look. Those are the best ways to clean things up.